# Automatically bin a long list of numbers in excel?

Tags: excel, bin, binning

Apologies, I've searched a fair bit and got nowhere. I have a column of values from 0 upwards (e.g., 0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.456, 0.9, 1.34, 2.76,3, etc.) in excel and I want to search the column and automatically select and do operations on all the values from (for example) 0-0.5, then 0.5-1 etc. - essentially I'm binning the data, but I want to keep the individual values, and not just make a cumulative histogram. Right now I'm doing it manually but I've got loads of data and it's painful! Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Well, to just give you one way to do binning automatically, you can make a new column with a formula like `=CEILING.MATH(A1/0.5)`.

So you get bin numbers:

[image]